# Compile and Run Java Program from another Java Program and fetch the console

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Java Program(Server) which are given Java source codes from a client.
I know i can compile and execute them with some `Runtime.exec()` with javac and java commands, but is there any way to catch the messages created by the new created java program?
So if i would get a program which executes `System.out.println("Hello World")` i get the "Hello World" from the console as some sort of Stream or maybe also the errors when i execute the javac program for compiling?

Thank you in advance, i know there is already someone who have done this :)

Comment: Check out java.lang.ProcessBuilder , might meet your needs.

Comment: Consider security issues.

Comment: @AndyThomas Is there any way to give the Program just specifc rights on execute? So it could not take any information of the host, or mess something up

Comment: I'm not an expert, and the risks can be significant. Some possibilities include using RMI to grant security permissions to the untrusted code, or running in a sandboxed container.